# Configuring auto-complete mode on emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I decided to give emacs another try, but configuring it can be quite a pain. I wanted something to simple auto complete html tags and php functions, then I find the auto-complete mode.
I installed it through the packages interface in emacs through elpa. I followed the instructions(http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html) for installing the dictionaries, editing the .emacs file with:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
```

but when I start emacs I have the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/dev/.emacs':
Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-dictionary-directories
```

Starting emacs with the debug options I have the following:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Error while loading 50dictionaries-common: Symbol's value as variable is void: debian-aspell-only-dictionary-alist
Entering debugger...
find-library-name: Can't find library /usr/share/emacs/24E.3/lisp/subr.el
```

I tried many things already but to no avail. I checked the value of the 'load-path' variable and the dict folder is in it. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

Emacs does not recognize 'ac-dictionary-directories. You should put this line after (require 'auto-complete-config)